# Bash Variable in Mongo eval command inserts empty data

Tags: mongodb, bash, eval

I have a script that inserts data into Mongo from a CSV but I have to encrypt one of the columns before insertion.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12
do
        ENCRYPT_VAL="$f5" | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -pbkdf2 -salt -pass pass:{*****}
        if [ "$f4" = "m" ]
        then
        mongo a11_USER_gender --eval "db.m.insert({username: '$f1', first: '$f2', last: '$f3', gender: '$f4', dob: '$ENCRYPT_VAL', state: '$f6', municipality: '$f7', season: '$f8', continent: '$f9', elective: '$f10', f1: '$f11', airline: '$f12'})"
        echo "Male Original value: '$f5'"
        echo "Male Encrypted value: $ENCRYPT_VAL"
        else
        mongo a11_USER_gender --eval "db.f.insert({username: '$f1', first: '$f2', last: '$f3', gender: '$f4', dob: '$ENCRYPT_VAL', state: '$f6', municipality: '$f7', season: '$f8', continent: '$f9', elective: '$f10', f1: '$f11', airline: '$f12'})"
        echo "Female Original value: '$f5'"
        echo "Female Encrypted value: $ENCRYPT_VAL"
        fi
done < /root/FileName.csv
```

I'm able to see that the variable has been successfully assigned the value of the encryption and that the Mongo insertion was seemingly successful. However, when I access the data inside of Mongo itself it displays a blank for that column.
I'm absolutely lost as to what could be the cause. I've tried enclosing the variable inside of the eval command in various different ways. I know I could just encrypt and save the value to the CSV prior to insertion, but I still feel like my attempted solution should work?

Sample of Seemingly Correct Encryption:

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.9
connecting to:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/a11_USER_gender?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("7d51958e-1550-4abc-ad2e-dbb8f0297646") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.9
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
Female Original value: 'february 20 1987'
Female Encrypted value:
U2FsdGVkX1/bKsrdCX7844Ozr6PkYRZnVZRcguYSBJE=
```

Sample of Erroneous Mongo Entry Below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62c21fa9463288ccfaddba16"),
    "username" : "zc1615",
    "first" : "zeena",
    "last" : "crayton",
    "gender" : "f",
    "dob" : "",
    "state" : "ne",
    "municipality" : "coral_gables",
    "season" : "summer",
    "continent" : "asia",
    "elective" : "mad3301",
    "f1" : "williams",
    "airline" : "gol"
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text (or *links* to images of text). Just include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
ENCRYPT_VAL="$f5" | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -pbkdf2 -salt -pass pass:{*****}
```

Does not set `ENCRYPT_VAL` to the output of the `openssl` command. It temporarily sets `ENCRYPT_VAL` to the value of `$f5` (see below), and then runs `openssl` on null input (printing the result to the console). So:

- You're not capturing the output of `openssl`, and
- You're not actually setting `ENCRYPT_VAL` (this is why you end up with an empty string in Mongo)

If you want to capture the output of a command in a variable, use `$(...)`, like this:

```
ENCRYPT_VAL="$( echo "$f5" | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -pbkdf2 -salt -pass pass:{*****} )"
```

---

The Bourne shell and derivatives allow you to provide temporary environment to a command by prefixing the command with variable expressions. For example, we can do this:

```
$ FOO=bar sh -c 'echo $FOO'
bar
```

That sets the variable `FOO` in the environment of the `sh` command. It doesn't set a shell variable in the current shell and it doesn't change the environment of the current shell.

When you write:

```
ENCRYPT_VAL="$f5" | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -pbkdf2 -salt -pass pass:{*****}
```

You're using exactly that syntax, except you're not even specifying a command, so it is entirely a no-op.

Comment: Ok so that worked. But I had 2 questions:
1. I assume that the space before/after each parenthesis is needed?
2. What does the echo command do in your solution?(My novice understanding was that it was simply just a means of printing text to the terminal display.)

Comment: For number 2 I think I have a vague guess to echo's purpose, is echo used to pull the row/data from the CSV?

Comment: You're want to pass the value of `$f5` into the `openssl` command on standard input...so we `echo` the value and pipe it into `openssl`. You could also use a `<<<` expression (`openssl ... <<<"$f5"`).